# Understanding COUNT() as `count`,

Tags: mysql, php

I'm currently learning how to build a site in PHP mysql. However, I seem to fail to understand `COUNT() as count` and wouldn't mind some further explanation.

I get the principles of COUNT, 0 || 1, and how it returns all the values that pertain to that query. But, don't see how COUNT as count works.

Anyhow, this is how the code I'm writing goes - so we have a working example - and where I first became perplexed.

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) as `count`, 
       `id` 
FROM `user` 
WHERE `email`='$email' 
AND `password`='".md5$password."'";
```

If anyone can explain be a great help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is called a column alias.

An alias is used to give columns a new name for the result set. This can be used to name a column based on an expressions (because otherwise the expression wouldn't "have" a name) or to rename columns, e.g. because the select list contains columns from different tables with the same name:

```
select t1.foo as t1_foo,
       t2.foo as t2_foo
from t1
   join t2 on ...
```

returns a result with the columns `t1_foo` and `t2_foo`

or

```
select avg(salary) as avg_salary
from employees
```

Btw: using a reserved word as an object name (`count`) isn't such a good idea in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the help – yep understood alias', was just a bit baffled as to why the example used count – as you point out it is a reserved.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "select count(*) as `count` from tbl_name";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Now you can easily get the value of count as

```
echo $data['count'];
```

instead of

```
echo $data['count(*)'];
```

So as you see count is just an alias of count(*).